# Blackberry Custom LabelField

Tags: blackberry, labelfield

How to create a custom Label field that works similar to default LabelField 
issues : it should be able to take large texts and should be able to display them in different   lines if the length exceeds the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

The existing LabelField class already displays text on a different line if the length exceeds the screen width.  To increase the font size do something like this:

```
label.setFont(Font.getDefault().derive(Font.PLAIN, 18, Ui.UNITS_pt));
```

Comment: I think My question was not clear to you ? I will make it a bit clearer . I want to create a custom Label field so that I can pass some extra arguments to it together with the label field text . for doing show I am crating a custom label field that is extending label field .but this custom label field is not taking the default property of the label field i.e if the length of the label text exceeds the screen width it is not shifting the remaining texts to the next line .

Comment: If you replace your custom labelfield with a regular labelfield does the text go to the next line?  If not then it's probably a problem with your manager.  Otherwise it's probably a problem with your LabelField code, which methods are you overriding?

Comment: I am adding the custom label field to a vertical field manager so there is no problem with the manager. actually in my customlabel field I need to set extent of my of the field I think that is causing the problem.

Comment: That probably is your problem.  I can't help you any more than that without seeing your LabelField code.

Comment: K thanks  Jonathan, I got an alternate way to implement my requirement and is now working fine.

Comment: Hey  Jonathan can u help me with another problem ..... In my Blackberry Application I want to set alarm at a particular date in a particular time with a reminder text eg "2011-01-26 at 11 pm "Go to Office"".....